# Sign PDF with already created CMS Signature c#

Tags: c#, pdf

I want to sign a PDF by an external service, that asks for a PDF in BASE64 Formate and the response contains a CMS Signature for this PDF.

How can I add this Signature to the PDF?

I checked the CMS via https://lapo.it/asn1js/# and it is valid.

Comment: you have to prepare a pdf for signing. A simple external signature of the original pdf cannot be used for integrating into the pdf.

Comment: for backgrounds cf. https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096

Comment: @mkl thanks! Do you know any packages that support that feature. PDFSharp for instance, does not.

Comment: Well, iTextSharp for example does. But I actually would expect this feature in any general-purpose PDF library. Are you sure PDFSharp really does not support it?

Comment: I'd expect such service to return the signed PDF, not the signature. In theory you can try this: sign the PDF with a dummy certificate so that you have the required entries in the PDF. Upload the signed PDF to your service for computing the signature. Assuming the service honors the /ByteRange entry in the file, you can take the generated signature and overwrite the /Content entry in the signature dictionary with your signature. If the service computes the signature over the whole file then you have no use for the generated signature as it cannot be used in a PDF file.

Comment: The Service I have to use, offeres an envelpoing function, where the generated signator is computed over the whole file, and the detached function, where only a signature is generated. 

I wish, they were so thoughtfull and would have just singed it and returned a finished pdf. but unforutnetly they only return the signature. 

So you suggest, I should use a dummy certificate and then overwrite it, with the actual CMS signature i get?

Answer (score 0):

You can all an external program through System.Diagnostics.Process.Start()

Have a look to the following link, which talks about free programs to do that:
http://wiki.cacert.org/PdfSigning

Comment: Thanks. But that does not help. I do not have a certificate, because the private key and the certificate are held by the service i talk to. 
I need to know, how to process the cms signature and add it to the pdf